# changelist_view in Django

Tags: django, django-views

How can I call changelist_view from my_app.views? I need save the render HTML to file/db

```
def view_to_string(self, request, extra_context=None):
        from django.template.loader import render_to_string
        from django.http import HttpResponse
        import codecs
        file = super(ProjectAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=Non
        f = codecs.open('/home/django/workfile', 'w', encoding="UTF-8")
        f.write(str(file).decode("utf8"))
        f.close()
```